# Server side Javascript in Marketing Cloud not updating data correctly

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs

I am trying to update data in a data extension using a SSJS activity in automation studio. I've debugged the code in a browser and everything seems to be working correctly but when I run the activity, the updated data is not being correctly evaluated in an if statement. The field I am trying to update is called Shipment_Status. The condition "if (trackingNumber.search("1Z") === 0)" seems to always be evaluating to true because every record shows "UPS" even if the tracking number doesn't start with "1Z".

Here is my script in the activity:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

//Initiate original data from
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows("Orders_With_Tracking",["Track"],["Track"]);


/*
    Orders_With_Tracking data extension fields:
    OrderID
    Tracking_Numbers
    Order_Status
    Shipping_Status
    Completed_Date
    Track
*/

if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
        var trackingNumber = dataRows[i]["Tracking_Numbers"].split(",")[0].toString();
        var orderId = dataRows[i]["OrderID"].toString();
        if (trackingNumber.search("1Z") === 0){
            //EXECUTE FOR UPS ORDERS
            var updatedRows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("Orders_With_Tracking",["OrderID"],[orderId],["Shipping_Status"],["UPS"]);
        } else {
            //EXECUTE FOR FEDEX ORDERS
            var updatedRows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("Orders_With_Tracking",["OrderID"],[orderId],["Shipping_Status"],["FEDEX"]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

After banging my head against the wall for 2 hours, I created test data to debug in browser - everything works fine and I cannot figure out why it does not work in SSJS. Here is the sample data:

```
var trackingNumber = "", updatedRows = 0, dataRows = [];
dataRows.push({
        OrderID : "801440000012eqeAAA",
        Tracking_Numbers : "1Z402W7FA893865507",
        Order_Status : "Completed",
        Shipping_Status : "",
        Completed_Date : "Monday, June 11, 2018 12:00 AM",
        Track : "Track"
}, {
        OrderID : "801440000012eqjAAA",
        Tracking_Numbers : "781395764744",
        Order_Status : "Completed",
        Shipping_Status : "",
        Completed_Date : "Monday, June 11, 2018 12:00 AM",
        Track : "Track"
}, {
        OrderID : "801440000012eqbAAA",
        Tracking_Numbers : "1Z402W7FA893865856",
        Order_Status : "Completed",
        Shipping_Status : "",
        Completed_Date : "Monday, June 11, 2018 12:00 AM",
        Track : "Track"
});
```

Thank you in advance!